# Intercept HTML (output) from PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that prints out HTML by means of echo's and also by printing it outside of the  tags (see example below).  What I would like to do (for MVC purposes), is to be able to intercept the output stream generated by both methods so that I can pass that into a display formatting function.

I have tried using ob_start(), etc, but this only intercepts the echo'd data.

Example:

```
<?php
function doLogicStuff()
{
  echo "This is some text.";  //You can intercept this using ob_start()
  ?>
    <b>This is some more HTML stuff</b>  <!-- This will not be intercepted by ob_start() -->
  <?php
}
?>
```

I would like to be able to intercept the complete "end result" of the output of that function so that I can pass it into a function tasked with the displaying thereof in a uniform way.

Is there a way to do that, or would it be easiest to write EVERYTHING into a string variable and return that (this will of course do the trick, but it's so annoying having to do that for large chunks of HTML).

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you aren't starting ob_start() soon enough? It works as expected when I do this on my sites.

Comment: Erm... actually, these are not different. Check the [ob_start documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#example-455): as you see, the output buffered in the example is echo-less. )

Comment: `ob_start()` should catch it, like normal output.

Comment: Function called `doLogicStuff()` doesn't seem like a good place to put presentation in. That being said, maybe I'm missing something here, but why not just return a HTML string?

Comment: Check [this example](http://codepad.org/onYupWxE) to see that both outputs (with and without PHP) will be collected into the buffer. )

Comment: Thank you all (esp @raina77ow for the trouble).  Seems I was just using it wrong.  Works like a charm now!